# Rails: What does the unique hex value represent in my exception for #<Task:0x98438b8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I'm new to rails and have been wondering the following lately:"

What does the hex value (e.g. `0x98438b8`) represents in exceptions like

`undefined local variable or method "company_id" for #<Task:0x98438b8>`

And how is this useful in debugging?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On MRI (Matz's Ruby Interpreter - the standard implementation of Ruby), it's the value of the underlying memory address, which is closely connected to the  [object_id](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-object_id). The exact relationship is platform dependant - on my machine it's twice the object id [see source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/gc.c#L754). Other implementations (jruby, mruby, rubinius) may well implement this differently.

In this particular case it's not particularly helpful. In other cases knowing that this is instance of Task is the exact same object as some previous value might be useful.

Comment: It's a unique id, but I never find that it matches the `object_id`

Comment: Hah, i'd never noticed that it's actually 2*object_id

Comment: Wow, yes, how did you spot that?

Comment: Please explain 'on MRI'... :-)

Comment: @SteveTurczyn got curious after your comment, so checked the source